# Cannot put state in query context

Tags: go, blockchain, hyperledger

Im trying to use a ticker in my chaincode to update the chaincode state periodically, based on some condition:

```
func (t *SimpleChaincode) Invoke(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {

  ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 10000)
    go func() {
        for t := range ticker.C {
            fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
            a = a+5
            err:= stub.PutState("a", []byte(strconv.Itoa(a)))     
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }
    }()

return nil, nil
```

}

I am sending the invoke transaction using the chaincode REST api for invoke :

```
POST http://<ip>:<port>/chaincode
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "invoke",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID":{
        "name":"c7b3c82f1170423115dcfc2524189f96f156b30961e0a0e84426c425c22f3b4e8b6ecbf477b76e014bfce74b996dee476a2470cbddc14d390617192f00c22c38"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
        "function":"invoke",
        "args":[]
    },
 "secureContext": "tom"
 },
  "id": 1
}
```

But PutState is failing with the following log:

```
2016/05/20 13:44:04 [8bcbe40e]Inside putstate, isTransaction = false
Tick at 2016-05-20 13:44:04.609079034 +0000 UTC
Cannot put state in query context
Tick at 2016-05-20 13:44:14.609093012 +0000 UTC
Cannot put state in query context
2016/05/20 13:44:14 [8bcbe40e]Inside putstate, isTransaction = false
Tick at 2016-05-20 13:44:24.609070317 +0000 UTC
Cannot put state in query context
```

Why is ***isTransaction = false*** , and why does it consider this context as a **query context**  ?

Comment: Can you edit and share the command you use to run this chaincode? You should use `peer chaincode invoke` or similar.

Comment: @dubek im using the chaincode REST api to invoke the chaincode function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original invoke transaction has completed and returned. The PutState from goroutine continues outside the transaction context (becoming, as it were, "a transaction" initiated by the chaincode itself). This is not allowed. All interactions with the ledger **have** to be part of an external transaction.

Comment: Is there any way for me to set state in a daily loop routine? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617003/is-it-possible-to-set-the-world-stateledger-in-a-go-routine